# Radzen Blazor Component Master Detail RadzenDataGrid How to Edit Multiple Details

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, radzen

I am new to Blazor Server Application. I am working on a simple order management system. I am using Radzen Blazor components. I have this master-detail blazor page where I want to edit selected orders' details. I checked the component documentation but I failed. How can I update multiple order details at once? I think of  making order details to edit mode by clicking a button and updating all the related order details with another button, but I couldn't find how to do it.

Here is my Blazor:

```
@page "/orders"
@using IMS.CoreBusiness
@using IMS.Plugins.EFCore.Migrations
@using IMS.UseCases.Interfaces.Order
@using IMS.UseCases.Interfaces.OrderDetail


@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IViewAllOrdersUseCase ViewAllOrdersUseCase
@inject IAddOrderUseCase AddOrderUseCase
@inject IEditOrderUseCase EditOrderUseCase
@inject IAddOrderDetailUseCase AddOrderDetailUseCase
@inject IEditOrderDetailUseCase EditOrderDetailUseCase

<h1>Orders</h1>
<RadzenButton Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Add New Order" Click="@InsertRow" Disabled=@(_orderToInsert != null) /> 
    <RadzenDataGrid @ref="_grid" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" RowRender="@RowRender" ExpandMode="DataGridExpandMode.Single"
                Data="@_orders" TItem="Order" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Single" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow" @bind-Value="@SelectedOrders" 
                ShowExpandColumn="true" >
        <Template Context="order">
            <RadzenCard Style="margin-bottom:20px">
                Vendor:
                <b>@order.VendorName</b>
            </RadzenCard>
            <RadzenTabs>
                <Tabs>
                    <RadzenTabsItem Text="Order Details">
                        <RadzenButton Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Add Order Detail" Click="@InsertDetailRow" Disabled=@(_detailToInsert != null) />
                        
                        <RadzenDataGrid @ref="_gridDetail" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" Data="@(SelectedOrders.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails)" 
                        TItem="OrderDetail" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRowDetail" RowCreate="@OnCreateRowDetail" >
                            <Columns>
                                
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="Id" Title="Product Number" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductCode" Title="Code">
                                    <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                        <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.ProductCode" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="ProductCode" />
                                        <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Product Code is required" Component="ProductCode" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                                    </EditTemplate>
                                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductName" Title="Name">
                                    <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                        <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.ProductName" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="ProductName" />
                                        <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Product Name is required" Component="ProductName" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                                    </EditTemplate>
                                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="UnitCost" Title="Unit Cost">
                                    <Template Context="detail">
                                        @String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}",detail.UnitCost)
                                    </Template>
                                    @*<EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                        <RadzenNumeric ShowUpDown="false" TValue="double?" @bind-Value="orderDetail.UnitCost" Class="w-100" />
                                        @*<RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.UnitCost" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="UnitCost" />
                                        <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Unit Cost is required" Component="UnitCost" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                                    </EditTemplate>*@
                                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="BuyQuantity" Title="Buy Qty" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="SellQuantity" Title="Sell Qty" />
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ShippingNumber" Title="Shipment"/>
                                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Context="orderDetail" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120px">
                                    <Template Context="detail">
                                        <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRowDetail(detail))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                                        </RadzenButton>
                                    </Template>
                                    <EditTemplate Context="detail">
                                        <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => SaveRowDetail(detail))">
                                        </RadzenButton>
                                        <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => CancelEditDetail(detail))">
                                        </RadzenButton>
                                    </EditTemplate>
                                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </RadzenDataGrid>
                    </RadzenTabsItem>
                    
                </Tabs>
            </RadzenTabs>
        </Template>
        <Columns>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="Id" Title="Order ID" Width="120px" />
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="CustomerName" Title="Customer" Width="200px">
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.CustomerName" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="CustomerName" />
                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Customer Name is required" Component="CustomerName" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="OrderDateTime" Title="Order Date" Width="200px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    @String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", order.OrderDateTime)
                </Template>
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value="order.OrderDateTime" DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" Class="w-100" />
                    @*<RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value="order.OrderDateTime" Style="width:100%" DateFormat="d" />*@
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="Status" Title="Status" Width="100px">
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.Status" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="Status" />
                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Status is required" Component="Status" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="DoneBy" Title="Employee">
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.DoneBy" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="DoneBy" />
                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="DoneBy is required" Component="DoneBy" Popup="true" Style="position:absolute"/>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRow(order))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </Template>
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => SaveRow(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                    <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => CancelEdit(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            @*<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="60px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="delete" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => DeleteRow(order))"  @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </Template>
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="delete" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => DeleteRow(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>*@
        </Columns>
    </RadzenDataGrid>
@code {
   
    IList<Order?> SelectedOrders { get; set; }
    IList<OrderDetail> _selectedDetails;

    IEnumerable<Order?> _orders = new List<Order?>();

    RadzenDataGrid<Order?> _grid;
    RadzenDataGrid<OrderDetail> _gridDetail;

    Order? _orderToInsert;
    OrderDetail _detailToInsert;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _orders = await ViewAllOrdersUseCase.ExecuteAsync();
        SelectedOrders = new List<Order?>(){ _orders.FirstOrDefault() };

    }

   
    void RowRender(RowRenderEventArgs<Order> args)
    {
        if(args.Data.OrderDetails != null)
            args.Expandable = args.Data.OrderDetails.Count > 0;
        
        
    }
    

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            _grid.ExpandRow(_orders.FirstOrDefault());
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }


    private async Task InsertRow()
    {
        _orderToInsert = new Order();
        await _grid.InsertRow(_orderToInsert);
        
    }
    private async Task InsertDetailRow()
    {
        _detailToInsert = new OrderDetail();
        await _gridDetail.InsertRow(_detailToInsert);
    }

    private async Task OnCreateRow(Order? order)
    {
        if (order != null)
        {
            await AddOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);

        }


    }
    private async Task OnCreateRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            await AddOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetail);

        }


    }
    private async Task OnUpdateRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order == _orderToInsert)
        {
            _orderToInsert = null;
        }

        if (order != null)
        {
            await EditOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);

        }
    }
    private async Task OnUpdateRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
        {
            _detailToInsert = null;
        }
        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            await EditOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetail);

        }
    }

    private void CancelEdit(Order? order)
    {
        if (order == _orderToInsert)
        {
            _orderToInsert = null;
        }

        _grid.CancelEditRow(order);


    }
    private void CancelEditDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
        {
            _detailToInsert = null;
        }

        _gridDetail.CancelEditRow(orderDetail);


    }

    async Task DeleteRow(Order? order)
    {
        if (order == _orderToInsert)
        {
            _orderToInsert = null;
        }

        if (_orders.Contains(order))
        {
            await _grid.Reload();
        }
        else
        {
            _grid.CancelEditRow(order);
        }
    }

    async Task DeleteRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
        {
            _detailToInsert = null;
        }


        if (_orders.All(x=>x != null && x.OrderDetails.Contains(orderDetail)))
        {
            await _gridDetail.Reload();
        }
        else
        {
            _gridDetail.CancelEditRow(orderDetail);
        }
    }
    async Task EditRow(Order? order)
    {
        await _grid.EditRow(order);
    }

    async Task EditRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        await _gridDetail.EditRow(orderDetail);
    }
    async Task SaveRow(Order? order)
    {
        if (order == _orderToInsert)
        {
            _orderToInsert = null;
        }

        await _grid.UpdateRow(order);
    }

    async Task SaveRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
        {
            _detailToInsert = null;
        }

        await _gridDetail.UpdateRow(orderDetail);
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem, hope helps someone.

```
@page "/orders"
@using IMS.CoreBusiness
@using IMS.Plugins.EFCore.Migrations
@using IMS.UseCases.Interfaces.Order
@using IMS.UseCases.Interfaces.OrderDetail


@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IViewAllOrdersUseCase ViewAllOrdersUseCase
@inject IAddOrderUseCase AddOrderUseCase
@inject IEditOrderUseCase EditOrderUseCase
@inject IAddOrderDetailUseCase AddOrderDetailUseCase
@inject IEditOrderDetailUseCase EditOrderDetailUseCase
<style>
    #wrapper { overflow: auto; }

    #c1 { float: right; }

    #c2 { float: right; }
</style>

<h1>Orders</h1>
<RadzenButton Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Add New Order" Click="@InsertRow" Disabled="@(_orderToInsert != null)"/>
<RadzenDataGrid @ref="_grid" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" RowRender="@RowRender" ExpandMode="DataGridExpandMode.Single"
                Data="@_orders" TItem="Order" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Single" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow" @bind-Value="@SelectedOrders"
                ShowExpandColumn="true" ShowPagingSummary="true">
    <Template Context="order">
        <RadzenCard Style="margin-bottom: 20px">
            Vendor:
            <b>@order?.VendorName</b>
        </RadzenCard>
        <RadzenTabs>
            <Tabs>
                <RadzenTabsItem Text="Order Details">
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <RadzenButton Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Add Order Detail" Click="@InsertDetailRow" Disabled="@(_detailToInsert != null)"/>
                        <RadzenButton Icon="save" style="margin-bottom: 10px; " Text="Save Details" id="c2" Click="@((args) => SaveRowDetails(SelectedOrders.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails))"/>
                        <RadzenButton Icon="border_color" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px" Text="Edit Details" id="c1" Click="@(args => EditRowDetails(SelectedOrders.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true"/>
                    </div>
                    <RadzenDataGrid @ref="_gridDetail" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" Data="@(SelectedOrders.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails)"
                                    TItem="OrderDetail" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRowDetail" RowCreate="@OnCreateRowDetail" AllowColumnResize="true" AllowColumnPicking="true" ShowPagingSummary="true" ColumnWidth="150px">
                        <Columns>

                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="Id" Title="Product Number"/>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductCode" Title="Code">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.ProductCode" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="ProductCode"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Product Code is required" Component="ProductCode" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductName" Title="Name">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.ProductName" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="ProductName"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Product Name is required" Component="ProductName" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="UnitCost" Title="Unit Cost">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenNumeric TValue="double" Min="1" @bind-Value="orderDetail.UnitCost" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="UnitCost"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Unit Cost is required" Component="UnitCost" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                                <Template Context="detail">
                                    @string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", detail.UnitCost)
                                </Template>
                               <FooterTemplate>
                                    <b>@string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", SelectedOrders?.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.UnitCost))</b>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="BuyQuantity" Title="Buy Qty">
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <b>@string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"), "{0:G}", SelectedOrders?.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.BuyQuantity))</b>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="SellQuantity" Title="Sell Qty">
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <b>@string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"), "{0:G}", SelectedOrders?.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.SellQuantity))</b>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="TotalBuyPrice" Title="Total Buy">
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <b>@string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", SelectedOrders?.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.TotalBuyPrice))</b>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="TotalSellPrice" Title="Total Sell">
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <b>@string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", SelectedOrders?.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.TotalSellPrice))</b>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ShippingNumber" Title="Shipment"/>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="TrackingNumber" Title="Tracking Number"/>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="Description" Title="Description"/>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Context="orderDetail" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120px">
                                <Template Context="detail">
                                    <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRowDetail(detail))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                                    </RadzenButton>
                                </Template>
                                <EditTemplate Context="detail">
                                    <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => SaveRowDetail(detail))">
                                    </RadzenButton>
                                    <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => CancelEditDetail(detail))">
                                    </RadzenButton>
                                </EditTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </RadzenDataGrid>
                </RadzenTabsItem>

            </Tabs>
        </RadzenTabs>
    </Template>
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="Id" Title="Order ID" Width="120px"/>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="CustomerName" Title="Customer" Width="200px">
            <EditTemplate Context="order">
                <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.CustomerName" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="CustomerName"/>
                <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Customer Name is required" Component="CustomerName" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="VendorName" Title="Vendor" Width="200px">
            <EditTemplate Context="order">
                <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.VendorName" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="VendorName"/>
                <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Vendor Name is required" Component="VendorName" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="OrderDateTime" Title="Order Date" Width="200px">
            <Template Context="order">
                @($"{order.OrderDateTime:dd/MM/yyyy}")
            </Template>
            <EditTemplate Context="order">
                <RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value="order.OrderDateTime" DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" Class="w-100"/>
               
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="Status" Title="Status" Width="100px">
            <EditTemplate Context="order">
                <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.Status" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="Status"/>
                <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Status is required" Component="Status" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="DoneBy" Title="Employee">
            <EditTemplate Context="order">
                <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.DoneBy" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="DoneBy"/>
                <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="DoneBy is required" Component="DoneBy" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120px">
            <Template Context="order">
                <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRow(order))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                </RadzenButton>
            </Template>
            <EditTemplate Context="order">
                <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => SaveRow(order))">
                </RadzenButton>
                <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@((args) => CancelEdit(order))">
                </RadzenButton>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        @*<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="60px">
                <Template Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="delete" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => DeleteRow(order))"  @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </Template>
                <EditTemplate Context="order">
                    <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="delete" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => DeleteRow(order))">
                    </RadzenButton>
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>*@
    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

@code {

    IList<Order?> SelectedOrders { get; set; }
    IList<OrderDetail> _selectedDetails;

    IEnumerable<Order?> _orders = new List<Order?>();

    RadzenDataGrid<Order?> _grid;
    RadzenDataGrid<OrderDetail> _gridDetail;

    Order? _orderToInsert;
    OrderDetail _detailToInsert;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _orders = await ViewAllOrdersUseCase.ExecuteAsync();
        SelectedOrders = new List<Order?>() { _orders.FirstOrDefault() };
    }


    void RowRender(RowRenderEventArgs<Order> args)
    {
        if (args.Data.OrderDetails != null)
            args.Expandable = args.Data.OrderDetails.Count > 0;
    }


    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            _grid.ExpandRow(_orders.FirstOrDefault());
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }


    private async Task InsertRow()
    {
        _orderToInsert = new Order
        {
            OrderDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>()
        };
        await _grid.InsertRow(_orderToInsert);

    }

    private async Task InsertDetailRow()
    {
        _detailToInsert = new OrderDetail();
        await _gridDetail.InsertRow(_detailToInsert);
    }

    private async Task OnCreateRow(Order? order)
    {
        if (order != null)
        {
            await AddOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);
        }
    }

    private async Task OnCreateRowDetail(OrderDetail? orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            await AddOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetail);
        }
    }

    private async Task OnUpdateRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order == _orderToInsert)
        {
            _orderToInsert = null;
        }

        if (order != null)
        {
            await EditOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);
        }
    }

    private async Task OnUpdateRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
        {
            _detailToInsert = null;
        }
        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            await EditOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetail);
        }
    }

    private void CancelEdit(Order? order)
    {
        if (order == _orderToInsert)
        {
            _orderToInsert = null;
        }

        _grid.CancelEditRow(order);
    }

    private void CancelEditDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
        {
            _detailToInsert = null;
        }

        _gridDetail.CancelEditRow(orderDetail);
    }

    async Task DeleteRow(Order? order)
    {
        if (order == _orderToInsert)
        {
            _orderToInsert = null;
        }

        if (_orders.Contains(order))
        {
            await _grid.Reload();
        }
        else
        {
            _grid.CancelEditRow(order);
        }
    }

    async Task DeleteRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
        {
            _detailToInsert = null;
        }


        if (_orders.All(x => x != null && x.OrderDetails.Contains(orderDetail)))
        {
            await _gridDetail.Reload();
        }
        else
        {
            _gridDetail.CancelEditRow(orderDetail);
        }
    }

    async Task EditRow(Order? order)
    {
        await _grid.EditRow(order);
    }

    async Task EditRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        await _gridDetail.EditRow(orderDetail);
    }

    async Task EditRowDetails(IList<OrderDetail?> SelectedOrders)
    {
        foreach (var detail in SelectedOrders)
        {
            await _gridDetail.EditRow(detail);
        }
    }

    async Task SaveRow(Order? order)
    {
        if (order == _orderToInsert)
        {
            _orderToInsert = null;
        }

        await _grid.UpdateRow(order);
    }

    async Task SaveRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
        {
            _detailToInsert = null;
        }

        await _gridDetail.UpdateRow(orderDetail);
    }

    async Task SaveRowDetails(IList<OrderDetail?> SelectedOrders)
    {
        foreach (var detail in SelectedOrders)
        {
            if (detail == _detailToInsert)
            {
                _detailToInsert = null;
            }

            await _gridDetail.UpdateRow(detail);
        }
    }
}
```